# Use switch case in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, switch-statement

I want to implement switch case for registration flow. Like normal sign up with

1. email, Phone number and password
2. with google
3. with facebook etc.

If user selects the *continue with google* button then switch to google registration and so on. How can I do that?

The controller file:

```
exports.register = catchAsync(async (req, res, error) => {
  try {
    const user = await userService.googleRegistration(req);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.failed(500, "Internal server error", error);
  }
});
```

The userService file:

```
// GOOGLE REGISTRATION
exports.googleRegistration = async (req) => {
  var google = require("googleapis").google;
  var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2();
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: req.params.access_token });
  var oauth2 = google.oauth2({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    version: "v2",
  });
  oauth2.userinfo.get(async (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
    } else {
      let user_data = new User({
        first_name: res.data.given_name,
        last_name: res.data.family_name,
      });
      let user = await user_data.save();
      return user;
    }
  });
};

// NORMAL REGISTRATION
exports.register = async (user) => {
  let new_user = new User({ ...user });
  const user_data = await new_user.save();

  const payload = { id: new_user._id };
  user_data.JWToken = jwt.sign(payload, keys.JWToken, { expiresIn: 31556926 });

  return user_data;
};
```

Comment: switch case is just an if else statement that has a less repeating syntax in exchange for only accepting one lefthand value

Comment: I am aware of that but How to switch according to user clicks on a button? can you show the implementation with the code?

Comment: saying you want a switch case is misleading.. you have different buttons with different logics and that's all.

Comment: yes just run the function on given button click

Comment: You can create these 3 buttons add value property to them and then add onClick event handler to them based on the value show different exports and their results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomended use an des-structuct object. NOT recomended use a switch it is bad for the memory and performance

```
const typeSingIn = {
 facebook: function(){ /* function to join with fb */},
 google: function() {/* your function to join with google*/},
 // more options
}

app.post("/singIn", (req, res) => {
 const {method} = req.body // expect the answer if the signIn is for fb, google or other method.
 const singInType = typeSignIn[method]
 try{
  signInType() // this can be a promise if you want it
 }catch(e){
  res.json({status: 500, message: e})
 }
})
```

Comment: the {method} have to be equal to the key of Object "typeSingIn"

Comment: Your solution is good but there is one problem. I am using the service oriented architecture that is why I am sending the request from the controller to the service file (As you can see in my controller.js file) but how can I send request now?

Comment: You can use a (req, res, next) router before the Controller. Verify the req.body and send the data with next(method) and with this method, already you know what Controller you need to execute (google, fb, etc...)